# wood expansion joints

Tags: wood, driveway, joints

My wood expansion joints are fine, but the gaps between the wood and the concrete is very wide in spots. The driveway is cracking from the water getting underneath, I believe. Can I simply use clear caulk to fill between the concrete and the wood?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to get concrete to be waterproof.  The correct approach is to handle the water that does get through the joints properly.  That's the purpose of the gravel base and the drainage system.  Is your drain blocked?

Comment: Not enough info, not sure what Wood and concrete have to do with one another. But yes, you can use caulk to fill, but should you ??? cant say without more info. Water under concrete in and of itself is not a cause for cracking. More details about your concrete and how it is constructed is needed.